# Dropping columns with >N NaNs excluding specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, nan

I'm wondering if the there is a consice way to do exclude all columns with more than *N* NaNs, excluding one column from this subset.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0], 
                   [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Results in:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1
2   NaN NaN NaN 5
```

Running the following, I get:

```
df.dropna(thresh=2, axis=1)

    B   D
0   2.0 0
1   4.0 1
2   NaN 5
```

I would like to keep column 'C'. I.e., to perform this thresholding except on column 'C'.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the column back once you've done the thresholding. If you do this all on one line, you don't even need to store a reference to the column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                   [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
df.dropna(thresh=2, axis=1).assign(C=df['C'])
```

You could also do

```
C = df['C']
df.dropna(thresh=2, axis=1)
df.assign(C=C)
```

As suggested by @Wen, you can also do an indexing operation that won't remove column C to begin with.

```
threshold = 2
df = df.loc[:, (df.isnull().sum(0) < threshold) | (df.columns == 'C')]
```

The index here for the column will select columns that have fewer than `threshold` `NaN` values, or whose name is `C`. If you wanted to include more than just one column in the exception, you can chain more conditions with the "or" operator `|`. For example:

```
df = df.loc[
    :,
    (df.isnull().sum(0) < threshold) |
    (df.columns == 'C') |
    (df.columns == 'D')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[:,(df.isnull().sum(0)<=1)|(df.isnull().sum(0)==len(df))]
Out[415]: 
     B   C  D
0  2.0 NaN  0
1  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN NaN  5
```

As per Zero's suggestion

```
df.loc[:,(df.isnull().sum(0)<=1)|(df.isnull().all(0))]
```

EDIT :

```
df.loc[:,(df.isnull().sum(0)<=1)|(df.columns=='C')]
```

Comment: `df.isnull().all(0)` instead of `df.isnull().sum(0)==len(df)`?

Comment: @Zero Added , :)

Comment: This isn't really correct - it only works on this example because C is the only column that has all `NaN`. This will keep any column with all `NaN`, and not necessarily column C (if C doesn't have all `NaN`).

Answer (score 2):

Another take that blends some concepts from other answers.

```
df.loc[:, df.isnull().assign(C=False).sum().lt(2)]

     B   C  D
0  2.0 NaN  0
1  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN NaN  5
```